# Finding one sided derivative

Tags: calculus

I need a simple question answered.

for derivative $\dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$ and the equation is $\dfrac{1}{x}$ and I want to find the right side of the derivative at (1,1).

Would I just plug in $1$ for $x$ as $h$ approaches zero from the right? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you would just plug in $1$ for $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the general procedure:
$$
f'(1)=\lim_{h,0}\frac{f(h+1)-f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h,0}\frac{\frac{1}{h+1}-\frac{1}{h}}{h}=\lim_{h,0}\left(\frac{h}{h+1}-1\right)=\frac{0}{1}-1=-1
$$